# standard naming convention document of Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#

Where is the standard naming convention document of Visual Studio C#. net?

I want naming convention document for variables, functions/methods and form controls for C#.

Comment: Naming conventions for what? Projects? Solutions? Pages? Variables? By the way, what is urgent for you certainly isn't urgent for me.

Comment: @Henrik: apparently he has time to come to Stack Overflow to ask!

Comment: Sorry doods,
Was asking the same thing in the mean time, from my senior colleaque.
Plz guide me.

Comment: @Asad: please go back to your previous questions and accept answers that have solved your problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see Klaus' and Fredrik's answers for good online resources. This is just to add: A good source for naming conventions and design guidelines in general for .NET can be found in the book [Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613).

Answer (score 6):

Here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The nearest thing to what you are asking for should be the [Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx), which features [some naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx). Note that these guidelines deal only with names that are visible "from the outside". It does not discuss what to call internal parts of your code, such as private fields or local variables.

Answer (score 0):

The Encodo book provides some good best practise guidelines

Can be found here

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/encodocsharphandbook